# Extra files in each partition folder when saving file from azure databricks to blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I'm using databricks to mount to my blob storage with this function:

> dbutils.fs.mount()

So I am fetching data and saving data from/to blob. I have partitioned my path so the path looks like <container_name>/year/month/day/<blob_file>. When I save my csv file it creates additional files with the same name as my partition folder, that is /year/month/day. Below is a snapshot of how it looks like in folder month:
[image]

Comment: When you are saving your file, you are seeing an additional file like `month=11` as in the image. And you don't want this file to be generated? Is this the ask? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: yes that is correct. I have an additional file in `year=2022` and `day=24` respectively

Comment: The contents of these files are empty, is this right?

Comment: yes, that is true